# javascript in pdf form if(this.getField("Global Region").value !=null){}

Tags: javascript, pdf

I am trying to lock down a pdf form if "Global Region" field is populated. It's long process to test the code. so I would like to make sure this is the correct syntax to check for NOT NULL in the Global Region Field.

```
if(this.getField("Global Region").value !=null)
{
//  my code here

}
```

Comment: Actually, this code is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The originally posted code is correct and works. I left out the first curly bracket and that's why it was not working.

```
if(this.getField("Global Region").value !=null)
{
//  my code here

}
```